# postgreSQL pg_dump Through LAN

Tags: postgresql, cron, pg-dump

I'm looking for a way to back up a database through a LAN on a mounted drive on a workstation.  Basically a `Bash` script on the workstation or the server to dump a single database into a path on that volume.  The volume isn't mounted normally, so I'm not clear as to which box to put the script on, given username/password and mounted volume permissions/availability.

The problem I currently have is permissions on the workstation:

```
myfile='/volumes/Dragonfly/PG_backups/serverbox_PG_mydomain5myusername_'`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M`'.sql'
pg_dump -h serverbox.local -U adminuser -w dbname > $myfile
```

Is there a syntax that I can provide for this?  Read the docs and there is no provision for a password, which is kind of expected.  I also don't want to echo the password and keep it in a shell script.  Or is there another way of doing this using `rsync` after the backups are done locally?  Cheers

Comment: So your problem was cron, not pg_dump. I suggest you add the `cron` tag to your question.

Comment: Well, the cron couldn't see pg_dump.  I will add it.

Answer (score 1):

First, note the `pg_dump` command you are using includes the `-w` option, which means `pg_dump` will not issue a password prompt. This is indeed what you want for unattended backups (i.e. performed by a script). But you just need to make sure you have authentication set up properly. The options here are basically:

1. Set up a [`~/.pgpass` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) on the host the dump is running from. Based on what you have written, you should keep this file in the home directory of the server this backup job runs on, **not** stored somewhere on the mounted volume. Based on the info in your example, the line in this file should look like:
   `serverbox.local:5432:database:adminuser:password`

   Remember to specify the database name that you are backing up! This was not specified in your example `pg_dump` command.
2. Fool with your Postgres server's `pg_hba.conf` file so that connections from your backup machine as your backup user don't require a password, but use something like [`trust`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST) or [`ident`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) authentication.  Be careful here of course, if you don't fully trust the host your backups are running on (e.g. it's a shared machine), this isn't a good idea.
3. Set environment variables on the server such as [`PGPASSWORD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) that are visible to your backup script. Using a `~/.pgpass` file is generally recommended instead for security reasons.

> Or is there another way of doing this using rsync after the backups are done locally?

Not sure what you are asking here -- you of course have to specify credentials for `pg_dump` **before** the backup can take place, not afterwards. And `pg_dump` is just one of many backup options, there are other methods that would work if you have SSH/rsync access to the Postgres server, such as [file-system level backups](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-file.html). These kinds of backups (aka "physical" level) are complementary to `pg_dump` ("logical" level), you could use either or both methods depending on your level of paranoia and sophistication.

Comment: Well it looks like I have all of this.  The modified syntax above actually represents the db name.  I'll change it.  Run manually in bash, it works fine.  In the crontab, it parks a result file that is empty.  crontab run as current user?  Can I take out the `-w`?

Comment: @josh-kuperschmidt `crontab -l` shows that specific script for my admin username, which is me.

Comment: @josh-kuperschmidt Just out of curiosity (the script broke for some reason, would you suggest pushing from server to archive, or pull from to archive machine from server?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with `~/.pgpass`, `pg_hba.conf` on the server, and a script that included the `TERM` environment variable (`xterm`), and a path to `pg_dump`.

There is no login for the `crontab`, even as the current admin user.  So it's running a bit blind.